# How to boot into text mode in Linux Mint LMDE (Debian-based)

Tags: boot, debian, linux-mint, runlevel, text-mode

Ok, this might sound ridiculous, but of all the issues I could have, I'm scratching my head over booting into text mode. Normally I'm in the opposite direction, such as `startx` not working.

To put the wtf-level of this into perspective, I just managed to run Photoshop CS5 without problems (I'm trying to go into text mode to install nVidia graphics drivers).

Speaking of levels, the runlevels concept is confusing me; Debian seems to have a default runlevel of 2 - in the [readme](ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/96.43.20/README/README.txt) for the drivers it says such a runlevel would be text mode, and not even have networking (and that the "default" would be 5).

Just to clear that up, on this Debian, `/etc/inittab` says:

```
# The default runlevel.
id:2:initdefault:
```

Then, I think about booting into "recovery mode", which is text-only. I have a gut feeling that's not the way to do it, as I'm not trying to "recover" anything, and I don't even know what changes in that mode.

So I google, and [a post](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/460) says I should edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. But that file says at the beginning:

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
```

And I really don't feel comfortable editing a file that says that.

Then I find [this other post](http://www.debianadmin.com/howto-boot-debian-in-text-mode-instead-of-graphical-mode-gui.html), Debian-specific. Basically it says to go root and disable the login manager:

```
# update-rc.d -f gdm remove
```

I was just going to try that out, but some commenters disagreed, some saying I should move a file:

```
# mv /etc/rc2.d/S30gdm /etc/rc2.d/K70gdm
```

Other put this in his `.bash_profile`:

```
if [ "$(echo $(who am i)|awk '{print $2}')" = "tty1" ]; then startx;logout;fi
```

(don't ask me what that means) Somebody even mentions this as a solution:

```
# apt-get remove gdm
```

[image: Why?]

Could anybody tell me a sane, *simple* way of booting into text-mode on this Debian-based distro?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, I was going to try `update-rc.d gdm3 disable` as per [@Stew's suggestion](https://superuser.com/questions/389589/how-to-boot-into-text-mode-in-linux-mint-lmde-debian-based/). Before that, I thougth, hey, there are "some" updates due, so I let it get updates to the packages (amongs them, linux 2.6.* to 3.0.*).

When I rebooted, to my surprise, linux started in text mode. If I ran `startx` I could get into the graphical environment without problems, so what happened?

The linux commandline (the parameters to linux from grub) included `text`. Hey, I edited that before, but it didn't work! Now in the boot log it was showing "text" had gotten into the linux parameters.

Turns out...

[image: One does not simply edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg]

You shouldn't just `sudo nano /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and put "text" there, there's a big warning against it at the top of the file.

### The right way is to:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

And add "text" to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.
So if it looked like:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"

...you have to change it to:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet **text**"

And then (it says this at the top of the file, somehow I missed it):

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

And reboot.
I prefer this method over disabling a service, since it's what it should be: editing one line in a configuration file. The same process can be repeated, and, if you want, `startx` will bring you to the user graphical interface while in text mode.

To return to normal, of course, just edit the file again and `update-grub`.

Comment: This helped me a ton. Thanks. But I have a question: Does this stop Gnome from loading on boot? Or does it still load and the user is just presented text mode?

Comment: @MadBurn I have no idea at the moment, but you can check by running `top` in text mode, I believe Gnome's process is called gnome-session or something. If I'm not mistaken, it won't be loaded, but again I'm not sure. I'm glad my answer helped you out :)

Comment: I think it does stop the process from starting. I wasn't able to find anything in the process list that told me otherwise. All the top processes were just core system processes. Either way, my broken-down-laptop **Linux Mint 15 MATE** based home server runs like a champ now. :)

Comment: Hmmm, a broken old laptop as a server... pretty cool idea. I'm also sure your Gnome's not running because it's very prominent by resource usage on `top`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be surprised if it was really gdm and not gdm3 or something else which was your display manager.  `aptitude search '~i~Px-display-manager'` should give you a list of display managers you have installed.

Indeed `update-rc.d -f remote gdm3` would be an incorrect way of disabling the service.  It would work temporarily, but then it would reappear when gdm3 is upgraded.  This is documented in the update-rc.d manpage if you search for "A common system administration error".

`update-rc.d gdm3 disable` would be the recommended way to disable a service.

removing the display manager altogether is also a solution, but you might find that you do not like the results, You may find that because of the way auto-installed pacakges and meta-packages work together, your system suddenly wants to remove all of gnome. [here](http://tanguy.ortolo.eu/blog/article8/uninstall-meta-package) is a good discussion of this issue and how to work around it.

Comment: It seems you're right, it's gdm3. Indeed, I do not want to remove a package just to go into command-line mode, so I'll soon try `update-rc.d gdm3 disable` and report what happens. You know, it's been a few months since I used [another distro](http://www.slitaz.org/), under which by accident I discovered a shortcut that put me into text mode, it used [Openbox](http://openbox.org/) as a window manager. By chance Gnome doesn't have something similar, has it...? (I don't remember which was the shortcut).

Comment: Found an easier way in the process, and gosh, it's as easy as I expected it to be. Good nice ol' text mode :)